# Write to newly opened terminal window

Tags: c, linux, terminal, tty

As everything is file in Linux I would like to print to opened console in terminal window.

I have opened console in Linux and have written command `tty`. In output I have:

```
/dev/pts/25
```

This is the program that copies everything from `foo` file to `bar` and console:

```
/* Trivial file copy program using low-level I/O */

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define BSIZE 16384

void main()
{
  int fin, fout,con; /* Input and output handles */
  char buf[BSIZE];
  int count;

  if ((con  = open("/dev/pts/2", O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
    perror("open con ");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((fin  = open("foo", O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
    perror("foo");
    exit(1);
  }

  if ((fout = open("bar", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644)) < 0) {
    perror("bar");
    exit(2);
  }

  while ((count = read(fin, buf, BSIZE)) > 0)
  {
    write(fout, buf, count);
    write(con, buf, count);
  }

  close(fin);
  close(fout);
  close(con);
}
```

Unfortunately nothing is written in console window while `bar` contains needed information. How to write to console terminal window?

Comment: It works.  Try to strace program: check for -1 on syscalls. May be you have misspelled /dev/pts/25  with /dev/pts/2?

Comment: A wild guess: your pts is configured as a raw device. Enable a cooked mode (or at least `echo`), and you shall see the characters.

Comment: using ubuntu linux 14.04 and gcc, the posted code fails to compile as it does not have the right header files included for `write()` and `read()`  and `open()`   Suggest adding: `#include <unistd.h>` `#include <sys/types.h>` ` #include <sys/stat.h>`

Comment: Since your running under the linux OS, the signature for `main() always has the return type of `int`, not `void`

Comment: just for good coding practice, read() returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int` and the third parameter to write() is a `size_t` not an `int`  if you compile with the `-Wconversion` parameter, the compiler will tell you about those problems.  It should be noted that the 'implicit conversion' feature of C will correct this for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have opened console in Linux and have written command `tty`. In output I have:

```
/dev/pts/25
```

This is program that coppyes evrything from `foo` file to `bar` and console:

```
…
  if ((con  = open("/dev/pts/2", O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
…
```

Your program opens just a device `pts/2` different from `pts/25` which you say is your console.